# How to click on a link based on another cell in same row C# asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-table, tablerow

I have a landlord table, tenant table and a property table in my database.I have a html table that is dynamically created which shows the properties of the landlord that is signed in.When a tenant signs up it enters the propery ID which is the foreign key in the tenant table. When I click the view link on that html table, I would like it to be redirected to a new page showing the tenants that belong to that property.. I am unsure how to do this when the view link is clicked based on the property id in that row

[This is my html table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OgCC.png)
and here is the code for the dynamically created table

```
public partial class LandlordIndex : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //creating an empty string
    string checkEmail = String.Empty;
    //constructing a string called table that will be used to create a dynamic table
    StringBuilder table = new StringBuilder();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkEmail += Session["LandlordLogin"];
    //if session is not empty then show label with corresponding email used in log in
        if (Session["LandlordLogin"] != null)
        {
            lblWelcome.Text += Session["LandlordLogin"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
        //Creating a connection to my database using the connection string
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["rent-dbConnectionString1"].ToString();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
            //preparing a query which will select all properties matching the landlord that is logged in at that moment
            comm.CommandText = "select p.Property_Id, p.Property_Address, p.Property_Num_Of_Tenants, p.Property_Vacant from Properties p inner join Landlords l On p.Landlord_Id = l.Landlord_Id where l.Landlord_Id = p.Landlord_Id and l.Landlord_Email = '" + checkEmail + "'";
            comm.Connection = con;
            SqlDataReader rd = comm.ExecuteReader();
            //creating a table depending on the data that is selected from the query
            table.Append("<table border='2' class='table table-striped table-bordered'>");
            table.Append("<tr><th>Property Number</th>");
            table.Append("<th>Address</th>");
            table.Append("<th>Number of Tenants</th>");
            table.Append("<th>Vacant?</th>");
            table.Append("<th>View</th>");
            table.Append("</tr>");
            if (rd.HasRows)
            {
                while(rd.Read())
                {
                    table.Append("<tr>");
                    table.Append("<td>" + rd[0] + "</td>");
                    table.Append("<td>" + rd[1] + "</td>");
                    table.Append("<td>" + rd[2] + "</td>");
                    table.Append("<td>" + rd[3] + "</td>");
                    table.Append("<td><a href=''>View</a></td>");
                    table.Append("</tr>");
                }
            }
            table.Append("</table>");
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = table.ToString() });
            rd.Close();
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please use a GridVIew to display data instead of generating a string like that.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use a dynamically generated table instead of using a GridView like @VDWWD suggested?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Make another page for Displaying Tenants. i.e tenants.aspx

**2.** Send propertyId from current page while calling that page

```
Response.Redirect("tenants.aspx?Id="+propertyId );
```

**3.** In Page_Load() function of tenants.aspx get propertyId

```
if (Request.QueryString["Id"]!= null)
string propertyId = Request.QueryString["Id"];
```

**4.** Fetch tenants for that property by querying database.

**5.** Make dynamic table for tenants just as properties

Comment: I am unsure what step 2 involves, where do i place that line of code in regards to the code: table.Append("<td><a href=''>View</a></td>"); ? Thanks @Hasan Ali

Comment: I am unsure what step 2 involves, where do i place that line of code in regards to the code: table.Append("<td><a href=''>View</a></td>"); ? Thanks  @Hasan

Answer (score 0):

you can achive that using jquery or javascript

for of all you need to add an id to view link like:

```
<td><a id='"+rd[0]+"' href=''>View</a></td>
```

then you need to put the below code in head. **(if you are already using jquery the remove the jquery link)**

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a').click(function () {
            debugger;
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var redirecttoAnotherPage = location.href + "?id=" + id;
            window.open(redirecttoAnotherPage);
            return false;
        });
        });
    </script>
```

do let me know in case you need any help

Comment: This is what happened to the url when the link is clicked  
localhost:3277/LandlordIndex?id=1 and the page is simply refreshing the page.  I want it to open Tenant.aspx and display the tenants who have an id of the property when we clicked view.

Comment: This is what happened to the url when the link is clicked localhost:3277/LandlordIndex?id=1 and the page is simply refreshing the page. I want it to open Tenant.aspx and display the tenants who have an id of the property when we clicked view.

Comment: in place of location.href you need to mention you url with page ie. http://yourlocalhost:port/Tenent.aspx